# Magento 2 - Incompatible argument type, even though constructor parent call matches extended class

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection, setup-di-compile, extend, dicompilation

I try to extend this class from my own module, because I need to inject another dependency to the constructor and add a few new methods:

**vendor\aheadworks\module-wbtab\Block\Wbtab\ProductList.php**

```
namespace Aheadworks\Wbtab\Block\Wbtab;

use Aheadworks\Wbtab\Model\Source\BlockLayout;
use Aheadworks\Wbtab\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory as ProductCollectionFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\ResourceModel\Cart;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\Module\Manager;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper;
use Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render as PricingRender;

/**
 * Class ProductList
 *
 * @method int|null getProductId()
 * @method string getBlockTitle()
 * @method string getBlockLayout()
 * @method int getProductsLimit()
 * @method bool getDisplayAddToCart()
 *
 * @package Aheadworks\Wbtab\Block\Wbtab
 */
class ProductList extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related
{
    /**
     * Path to template.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'wbtab/product_list.phtml';

    /**
     * Product collection factory
     *
     * @var ProductCollectionFactory
     */
    private $productCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var PostHelper
     */
    private $postHelper;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Cart $checkoutCart
     * @param Visibility $catalogProductVisibility
     * @param Session $checkoutSession
     * @param Manager $moduleManager
     * @param ProductCollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
     * @param PostHelper $postHelper
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Cart $checkoutCart,
        Visibility $catalogProductVisibility,
        Session $checkoutSession,
        Manager $moduleManager,
        ProductCollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        PostHelper $postHelper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->postHelper = $postHelper;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $checkoutCart,
            $catalogProductVisibility,
            $checkoutSession,
            $moduleManager,
            $data
        );
    }

    ...

}
```

I created my extend block in:

**app\code\Company\Extend\Block\Wbtab\ProductList.php**

```
<?php

namespace Company\Extend\Block\Wbtab;

use \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context;
use \Aheadworks\Wbtab\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory as ProductCollectionFactory;
use \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility;
use \Magento\Checkout\Model\ResourceModel\Cart;
use \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;
use \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager;
use \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper;
use \Company\Base\Helper\Product as HfProductHelper;

class ProductList extends \Aheadworks\Wbtab\Block\Wbtab\ProductList
{

    private $productCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var PostHelper
     */
    private $postHelper;

    private $hfProductHelper;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Cart $checkoutCart,
        Visibility $catalogProductVisibility,
        Session $checkoutSession,
        Manager $moduleManager,
        ProductCollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        PostHelper $postHelper,
        HfProductHelper $hfProductHelper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->postHelper = $postHelper;
        $this->hfProductHelper = $hfProductHelper;

        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $checkoutCart,
            $catalogProductVisibility,
            $checkoutSession,
            $moduleManager,
            $data
        );
    }

    public function getProductById($id)
    {
        return $this->hfProductHelper->getProductById($id);
    }

    public function isProductNew($_product = null)
    {
        return $this->hfProductHelper->isProductNew($_product);
    }

    public function testFooBar()
    {
        return "test foo bar";
    }

}
```

**app\code\Company\Extend\etc\frontend\di.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="\Aheadworks\Wbtab\Block\Wbtab\ProductList"
                type="\Company\Extend\Block\Wbtab\ProductList" />
</config>
```

But if I execute `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` then I get:

> **Company\Extend\Block\Wbtab\ProductList**
>   Incompatible argument type: Required type:
>   **\Aheadworks\Wbtab\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory**.
>   Actual type: array; File:
>   /home/company/company.de/app/code/Company/Extend/Block/Wbtab/ProductList.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're missing passing two non-optional params (`$productCollectionFactory`, `$postHelper`) while calling parent::__construct. So that's how the call to parent::__construct should look like in extended class:

```
parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $checkoutCart,
            $catalogProductVisibility,
            $checkoutSession,
            $moduleManager,
            $productCollectionFactory,
            $postHelper,
            $data
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `\Company\Extend\Block\Wbtab\ProductList` constructor you are calling the constructor of the parent class `\Aheadworks\Wbtab\Block\Wbtab\ProductList` which expects 8 parameters, but you're only giving 6.

Update your constructor to the following:

```
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    Cart $checkoutCart,
    Visibility $catalogProductVisibility,
    Session $checkoutSession,
    Manager $moduleManager,
    ProductCollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    PostHelper $postHelper,
    HfProductHelper $hfProductHelper,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    $this->postHelper = $postHelper;
    $this->hfProductHelper = $hfProductHelper;

    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $checkoutCart,
        $catalogProductVisibility,
        $checkoutSession,
        $moduleManager,
        $productCollectionFactory,
        $postHelper,
        $data
    );
}
```